# How to read from firebase and display in rating bar

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ratingbar

I have a rating bar which is supposed to display individual user rating average depending on which user is logged in. A user can rate another user by writing to the database under the rating node as shown here[image: this is the view of the database under ratings]

The user who has been rated is under the node "ratee". please note '-LxW7A......' is a randomly generated key.
To view the user's rating in the event that he has been rated more than once I have used the code below to get the sum of the ratings and divide that by the total amount of times the user has been rated to get the average

```
FirebaseUser user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userId=user.getUid();
  DatabaseReference refund = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ratings");
Query query=refund.orderByChild("ratee").equalTo(userID);


final RatingBar ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar) ;
  query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
int count=0;
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     String rating=dataSnapshot.child("rater").getValue(String.class);
    if (rating==null){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"empty ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}else{
        count=count+Integer.valueOf(rating);
        double a = dataSnapshot.child("kutaPoints").getValue(double.class);
        totalpointsused =+ a;
        double tots=(double)count;
        double result=totalpointsused/tots;
        float abc=(float)result;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+abc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ratingBar.setRating(abc);
    }}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

The code above however does not work and nothing is displayed in the rating bar and the toast empty is being displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using the following query:

```
Query query=refund.orderByChild("ratee").equalTo(userID);
```

It means that the `DataSnapshot` object that you get as an argument in `onDataChange()` method contains a list of results. Even if there is a single result, as I see in your screenshot, the list will contain a single element. So when talking about a list, to get the elements we need to iterate through the list. So please check the following lines of code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long count = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long ratingg = ds.child("ratingg").getValue(Long.class);
            count = count + ratingg;
        }
        long avarage = count / dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Log.d("TAG", "avarage: " + avarage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Assuming that all 4 users have the value of `ratingg` property set to `4`, the result in your logcat will be:

```
avarage: 4
```

Comment: But how will I be able to get the average? For instance if they are 4 entries each with the value of 4 in the database for one user then the result will be 16, but what am trying to get is the average of the user's ratings

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Quick question, are you using long so that it may accept both doubles and ints?

Comment: @Yayayaya No, I'm using long because `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` returns a long value. You can cast it later as needed.